# Does a random variable have to be a total function on the space of outcomes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

A random variable is a function from the space of outcomes to real numbers (there are extensions to this, but it's not important for the purposes of this question: see wikipedia).

The question is: does the function have to be total? Can the function be partial? That is not defined on some elements the outcome space?

Edit: I thought I'd make up a simple example. 
Take each element to be result of 1000 6-side die rolls. Define a random variable $X$ to be the number of contiguous 2's after an initial sequence of four 6's. This variable is only applicable to the subset of elements that start with four 6's. It doesn't make sense to apply it to, say, an experiment which starts with a 1.

Comment: Allowing partial functions would make nonsense out of most formulas for expectations, moments, distribution functions, and every other form of analyzing random variables.  Do you have in mind some reason or application why it might be important to use partial functions?

Comment: If the domain $A \subset \Omega$ of your function $X$ is a member of the $\sigma$-algebra of the probability space, and has nonzero probability, then one could consider the mapping that we know as a random variable with known _conditional_ distribution $F_{X\mid A}(x \mid A)$ whose _unconditional_ distribution $F_X(x)$ will be forever unknown to us.

Comment: @whuber. I had the thought when solving a problem. Dilip's response is interesting. It's the same one I had. If we condition on a subset where the function is applicable, then we have a CPD and we can take expectations etc with respect to the CPD (which is what I was trying to do).

Comment: Of course you can do that.  But there's no need to generalize the definition of a random variable: all you're doing is applying the standard definitions to a subspace of the original space $\Omega$.

Comment: @whuber. Great. I think we've explored this question and understood it. If you can post what you have written as an answer, I can accept.